# SharePoint adds line breaks <BR> to messages received from Outlook

Tags: sharepoint, outlook-2007

I recently created a new discussion list in SharePoint for our group, and I set it to be able to receive emails. The issue is when the SharePoint discussion list receives an email it adds unwanted line breaks (in the form of 
) in between each line.

I wanted to know if there was script that could be run from my end to apply to emails being sent SharePoint that would tell it not to add the 
 tags. If that is not possible is there somewhere I could point our SharePoint Admin that may help him add some code so SharePoint would not add extra line breaks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is most likely due to the formatting of the email being sent to the discussion list, have you tried sending a format of plaintext email to see if it still does it? If so you may be able to resolve this by using css to not display the br tags in the specific element. i.e.. .discussionThreadClass br {display:none;}